# Android (Chrome) WebView - Javascript - HTML elements with horizontal scrollbars for overflowX

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview, overflow

My Android app has a WebView (min SDK API level 19 - Kitkat) that renders a HTML file with text and other elements. It injects JavaScript code too.

I see that many elements, dispite the overflowX settings I assign to them, still make the document.body overflow.

I managed to set the body not to overfow, while the elements must have "scroll" value to overflowX so the user can see them entirely.

```
document.body.style.width=window.innerWidth+"px";
document.body.style.maxWidth=window.innerWidth+"px";
document.body.style.overflowX="hidden";
var all = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) 
{ 
all[i].style.overflowX="scroll";
}
```

For example there are some

```
<pre>
```

elements.

They are horizontally scrollable but no horizontal scrollbar appears so the user is not able to know if ther is further content on the right.

I tried the scrollbar settings on the WebView but nothing changes.

How can I make the horizontal scrollbar appear on those elements, said that the overflowX='scroll' (or 'auto') setting is ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Try **overflowX='auto'** I hope it helps.

Comment: With 'auto' it's the same.

Comment: Can you try and post a snippet of your code so that i can better help you and replicate? I will do my best

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on your instance of webview.

webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)

Comment: sorry, nothing changes with your suggestion